# Android gps getlastknownlocation returns null pointer exception

Tags: android, networking, gps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

In my activity I need to get the current location of the mobile phone using gps. I have used the following code:

```
Location gpslocation;
LocationManager lmanager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
gpslocation= lmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

//error in the next line as follows java.lang.nullpointerexception

gpslatitude=gpslocation.getLatitude();
gpslongitude=gpslocation.getLongitude();
```

I know that getlastknownlocation will fetch the last location in which the gps was fixed. In this case getlastknownlocation is returning a null pointer. That's why the exception arises and my app force closes. Also I know that there is another method for getting the gps coordinates using onlocationchanged. But for this to work the device has to be in a moving situation for some distance. Since in my app I want to get the gps coordinates in a stationary manner, Is there any other way to get the gps coordinates using gps in android.

I don't want to use network provider because it would only give the coordinates of places which is about 5 kms distance from the actual position of my current location. So I wouldn't encourage the use of network location in my app. Since 5 km distance is not an acceptable range for me. Is there any other way for fixing the gps coordinates using code. And there by when using the lastknownlocation would fetch me an solution to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some devices doesn't support getLastKnownLocation (e.g. my Motorola XT720). You have to implement LocationListener and save location updates in onLocationChanged by yourself to database or sharedpreferences. And when getLastKnownLocation is null use that saved location.

EDIT:
Main problem with that approach is that when user moves a lot it isn't accurate. Another solution will be to write a service witch fires e.g. once a hour location manager, saves results and then you will have your "last location" updated every hour on older devices.

Comment: Its not that they don't support it-  its that they may not have one.  Tracking may have been turned off for so long it doesn't have a location saved.  If you were to request updates then use it after you've received one it would return properly.  And this is across ALL devices.

Comment: My device never had lastLocation, no matter when I asked for it - always null. Even if I ask right after onLoctionChange or after using other apps that uses GPS.

Comment: I don't have one of those devices specifically to test, but the way its supposed to work is that GLKL will return NULL if the result is stale or if it never had one, and will return non-null if it has one fresh enough.  I tend to doubt it was totally broken, although I will believe some devices may not return a result at all unless GPS is on.  Either way there's a better way than writing to a shared preference-  when he needs it he should call requestSingleUpdate instead.

Comment: @MateuszJablonski how to implement the onLocationChangeListener in android. Can you please help me..

Comment: just follow guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates

Comment: For how long do I have to wait for a gps fix. I think when I tried to implement from the above link, I still got a null pointer exception. This may be because a fix for the gps was not obtained. LocationManager locationmanager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Then I used the location listener to listen. After that I used
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
  gps=locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  Double lat,longi;
  lat=gps.getLatitude();
  longi=gps.getLongitude();

Comment: But still I was getting null pointer exception. What is the reason for this??

Comment: For how long do I have to request for location updates to get a proper gps fix. How is this done?? Can you please help me..